# Single Quote Error

Tags: sql, sql-server

When I insert single quote in search box and press search button it gives error like:

> [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client
>   10.0][SQL Server]Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ' '.

Comment: Parameterise your SQL! This is a sure sign that your application is vulnerable to SQL injection. What are you using? C#?

Comment: try searching for: `';drop table users;--`

Answer (score 2):

You should be using [parameterized queries](http://www.enterprisedb.com/documentation/dotnet-parameterizedqueries.html) instead of constructing your SQL by concatenation.

This will avoid [SQL Injection attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) as well as resolve any single quote issues.

The quick fix it to escape the `'` by doubling it (`''`), but this would just be a temporary workaround and your code will still be vulnerable.

Answer (score 0):

Parameterize your SQL queries. There are more serious issues than this called [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape single quotes, like \' as you're using single quotes to surround where-statements, like where i = 'foo', then you need to write where i = '\'' to match a single quote, or lie where i = 'it\'s a good day today'

Comment: And I do agree with Oded, use prepared/parameterized queries if you can

Comment: In SQL Server quotes don't get escaped in this manner anyway.

Comment: it is incorrect to say escape the single quotes with a slash: \   because SQL server escapes quotes with a single quote: ' , like @Oded says in his answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4387300/single-quote-error/4387318#4387318, also I didn't down vote you (you are sure to get some though)