# Search crashes when random characters '%^$^&%'?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, sql

Good afternoon fellow coders, I am running into an error here. You see my search crashes when I type in random characters such as the following: %^&*&%. Here's the error as well as the search code, see below:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Error in Like operator: the string pattern '%$%^$&^%' is invalid.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.EvaluateException: Error in Like
>   operator: the string pattern '%$%^$&^%' is invalid.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [EvaluateException: Error in Like operator: the string pattern
>   '%$%^$&^%' is invalid.]    System.Data.LikeNode.AnalyzePattern(String
>   pat) +1277726    System.Data.LikeNode.Eval(DataRow row, DataRowVersion
>   version) +341    System.Data.BinaryNode.Eval(ExpressionNode expr,
>   DataRow row, DataRowVersion version, Int32[] recordNos) +20
>   System.Data.BinaryNode.EvalBinaryOp(Int32 op, ExpressionNode left,
>   ExpressionNode right, DataRow row, DataRowVersion version, Int32[]
>   recordNos) +12960    System.Data.BinaryNode.Eval(DataRow row,
>   DataRowVersion version) +25
>   System.Data.BinaryNode.Eval(ExpressionNode expr, DataRow row,
>   DataRowVersion version, Int32[] recordNos) +20
>   System.Data.BinaryNode.EvalBinaryOp(Int32 op, ExpressionNode left,
>   ExpressionNode right, DataRow row, DataRowVersion version, Int32[]
>   recordNos) +12960    System.Data.BinaryNode.Eval(DataRow row,
>   DataRowVersion version) +25
>   System.Data.BinaryNode.Eval(ExpressionNode expr, DataRow row,
>   DataRowVersion version, Int32[] recordNos) +20
>   System.Data.BinaryNode.EvalBinaryOp(Int32 op, ExpressionNode left,
>   ExpressionNode right, DataRow row, DataRowVersion version, Int32[]
>   recordNos) +12960    System.Data.BinaryNode.Eval(DataRow row,
>   DataRowVersion version) +25
>   System.Data.BinaryNode.Eval(ExpressionNode expr, DataRow row,
>   DataRowVersion version, Int32[] recordNos) +20
>   System.Data.BinaryNode.EvalBinaryOp(Int32 op, ExpressionNode left,
>   ExpressionNode right, DataRow row, DataRowVersion version, Int32[]
>   recordNos) +12960    System.Data.BinaryNode.Eval(DataRow row,
>   DataRowVersion version) +25
>   System.Data.BinaryNode.Eval(ExpressionNode expr, DataRow row,
>   DataRowVersion version, Int32[] recordNos) +20
>   System.Data.BinaryNode.EvalBinaryOp(Int32 op, ExpressionNode left,
>   ExpressionNode right, DataRow row, DataRowVersion version, Int32[]
>   recordNos) +12960    System.Data.BinaryNode.Eval(DataRow row,
>   DataRowVersion version) +25
>   System.Data.DataExpression.Invoke(DataRow row, DataRowVersion version)
>   +145    System.Data.Index.AcceptRecord(Int32 record, IFilter filter) +101    System.Data.Index.InitRecords(IFilter filter) +297    System.Data.Index..ctor(DataTable table, IndexField[] indexFields,
>   Comparison`1 comparison, DataViewRowState recordStates, IFilter
>   rowFilter) +464    System.Data.DataTable.GetIndex(IndexField[]
>   indexDesc, DataViewRowState recordStates, IFilter rowFilter) +212
>   System.Data.DataView.UpdateIndex(Boolean force, Boolean fireEvent)
>   +159    System.Data.DataView.UpdateIndex(Boolean force) +12    System.Data.DataView.SetIndex2(String newSort, DataViewRowState
>   newRowStates, IFilter newRowFilter, Boolean fireEvent) +108
>   System.Data.DataView.SetIndex(String newSort, DataViewRowState
>   newRowStates, IFilter newRowFilter) +14
>   System.Data.DataView.set_RowFilter(String value) +158
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.FilteredDataSetHelper.CreateFilteredDataView(DataTable
>   table, String sortExpression, String filterExpression, IDictionary
>   filterParameters) +387
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceView.ExecuteSelect(DataSourceSelectArguments
>   arguments) +1830
>   System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments
>   arguments, DataSourceViewSelectCallback callback) +21
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.PerformSelect() +138
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.DataBind() +30
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.DataBind() +4
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.EnsureDataBound() +105 
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.CompositeDataBoundControl.CreateChildControls()
>   +75    System.Web.UI.Control.EnsureChildControls() +83    System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +42
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +168
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +168
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +168
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +168
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +168
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +974

And the code is:

> ```
>  public static bool IsDate(Object obj)
>         {
>             string strDate = obj.ToString();
>             try
>             {
>                 DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(strDate);
>                 if (dt != DateTime.MinValue && dt != DateTime.MaxValue)
>                     return true;
>                 return false;
>             }
>             catch
>             {
>                 return false;
>             }
>         }
>
>
>  protected void BtnWinnersSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
>         {
>
>             string searchText = txtWinnersSearch.Text.Replace("'", "''").Trim();
>             bool isDate = IsDate(searchText);
>
>             GridViewWinners.Visible = true;
>
>             if (isDate == true)
>             {
>                 SqlDataSource4.FilterExpression = "dob" + " ='" + Convert.ToDateTime(searchText).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "'";
>             }
>             else
>             {
>                 SqlDataSource4.FilterExpression = "nickname like '%" + searchText + "%' or username like '%" + searchText +
>                     "%' or clubnumber like '%" + searchText + "%' or firstname like '%" +
>                     searchText + "%' or lastname like '%" + searchText +
>                     "%' or email like '%" + searchText + "%'";
>             }
>         }
> ```

[image]

Comment: A form of this question/issue comes up on SO almost daily. Answer: Use parameters instead of dynamically generating your SQL. Besides avoiding errors you will also avoid SQL injection vulnerability. See here for one example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4387300

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now your code is vulnerable to a SQL Injection attack.

Switch to using  parameterized queries and I suspect it will fix your problem (as well as fix a huge security vulnerability you have right now...).  I'm guessing there is some value that is not being properly escaped when you submit "random characters".

[Here is an excellent link](http://software-security.sans.org/developer-how-to/fix-sql-injection-microsoft-.net-with-parameterized-queries) to get you started with parameterized queries.

Comment: Please don't feed this much-too-frequently duplicated question.

Comment: SelectCommand="SELECT [PlayerID], [Nickname], [UserName], [ClubNumber], [FirstName], [Email], [LastName], [DOB] FROM [Players] where Nickname like '%'+@Nickname+'%' order by lastname ASC">
                <SelectParameters>
                     <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtWinnersSearch" Name="Nickname" PropertyName="Text" Type="String"/>
                </SelectParameters>
            </asp:SqlDataSource>

Comment: The above comment solved my problem using your solution @Abe. thanks again!